# Are questions about the MSE chatrooms on topic on MSE? If so, how can we best to understand some cryptic room descriptions?

Tags: discussion, chat, scope

I'd like to know, basically, if questions about current MSE chat rooms are on topic on MSE. I'd like to know, because I have concerns about many MSE users, particular askers, likely are not able to readily find an appropriate chatroom (under MSE's umbrella) which doesn't presume the users are regular answerers or well-known users on MSE.

- Tavern on the Meta room description: "MY GOD, IT'S FULL OF STARS AND BACKLOG! Wheel of blame link bolted on for your ease of use: jsfiddle.net/Ldvwp8uv/12/embedded/result".
- Shadows Den room description: "Where words are being associated, a black hedgehog is lurking, and new spells are given. And pings are allowed, so enter at your own risk! Quote of the decade: "No two people are the same, but everyone is worth the same." (@PrincessLuna)."
- Top Secret room description: none.
- Let's get philosophical room description: "It's like a song or something."

The majority of MSE chatrooms are rather cryptic in their descriptions to an interested user "not already in the know."  I'm asking this question, because I'd rather not reach the conclusion that the chatrooms I list are intentionally exclusionary/exclusive. I have not reached that conclusion yet, but I've yet to see anyone holding such chatroom accountable for an honest description of what is on and what is off topic.

I have tried to express this concern on four separate MSE chat-rooms, to no avail.

I'd like to know why some MSE regulars create such eclectic chatrooms, for which information about the chats are so cryptic? Are chatroom owners, of the sites I mention, seeking to be resources for users, or not?  And if not, why not?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean here. MSE has one _main_ chatroom, the [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). Any other chatrooms on MSE are generally rooms created by specific users for a specific purpose, rather than to be alternative venues for general chat.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I mean many, but not all, of the chatrooms one finds when clicking on "chat" under the right-most icon in the top banner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the biggest disconnect you're having here is that chatrooms on MSE aren't really... intended... for anything, beyond random chatter.

There's one "main" chatroom on MSE, and that's the [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). A bunch of people hang out there; sometimes some staff do too; it's also the place if you want to talk about this site, Meta Stack Exchange. Other than that, it's used as a place to shoot the Stack Exchange breeze.

The other rooms on the MSE chat server are more informal rooms. They're often rooms that have been created by one or a few users, mostly for chatting amongst a group of people who get along well. These rooms also don't really have a purpose, and their descriptions reflect that - mostly, anything goes.

If you're looking for somewhere to put anything that's remotely approaching serious discussion, you want the Tavern. Other than that, if you want to hang around and chat, feel free to drop into the other rooms and take a look around. If you're looking for a room about a particular topic, you'll be better served by looking at chat rooms on the chat.stackexchange.com server instead.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, @ArtofCode.  I have made efforts to immerse myself in the environments of a number of the chatrooms I've been, and indeed, users in "Tavern on the Meta" have been most receptive.  I'm a relatively new user to MSE, but I've been active for a couple of months. Just the same, I am hoping only that users in the chat, or Shadow's Den, are more welcoming of not new on SE, not terribly new on MSE, users, who stop in trying to join in even merely friendly chatting. I've had some positive experience on "Tavern on the Meta" by a couple of users. But it remains rather "cliquey"?

Comment: Also, if I may add, "Tavern" is mostly "chatty", from my experience in stopping in over the past two months. It would be great if Tavern had a room description inclusive of "serious" questions, and idle chat, as well.

Comment: Room description changed, @Namaste. Tavern is a bit of a mixed bag - it really depends who you find in there as to what experience you come out of it with, if you're new to the room in general. Once you've lurked there for a while it becomes more familiar, but that's not possible for everyone so it can seem a bit hit and miss to start with.

Comment: Yeah, that's been my experience.  But it my experience there has improved, thanks to a few users who frequent the chat. I just edited the title to encompass my question.  Thanks again.

Comment: You also assume even we know what the channel topic is about.... Honestly we just have been altering what was there from as far back as I can remember

Comment: @JourneymanGeek If that's the case, maybe it's time to state clearly, and *know* what the channel topic is about.  Poor excuse, for intentionally cryptic room descriptions, especially coming from you.  "It's always been like this..." doesn't justify a darn thing.

Comment: why does it *need* to be descriptive? it's not like we're trying to drive people to it.

Comment: No, @KevinB, more like they're trying to keep people *out*. And what makes you say "we"? (in "it's not like **we**'re trying...). Your *need* to feel like you *belong*, any more than anyone else??

Comment: Assume good faith - that goes for everyone. Kevin - it's always worth considering if The Old Ways (tm) can be changed to make things easier on people who don't know them. Namaste - a room description being worded a certain way doesn't imply the room is trying to keep people out; AFAIK it was that way simply through evolution without any real direction over the years.